# The SDK platform-tools version (24.0.4) is too old to check APIs compiled with API 25; please update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-7.0-nougat, platform-tools

I am getting this error on the latest version of Android Studio and while I have installed both Android SDK Platform API 25 and Android SDK Build-Tools 25.

Comment: This means you are Importing Project that required version 25 but you currently have 25.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Updating Android Studio to version 2.2.2 (latest at the time of this writing) and Gradle version to 2.2.2 (latest at the time of this writing) in `project_name/build.gradle` file fixed this issue.

For reference, this is my config in `project_name/app/build.gradle` file:

```
minSdkVersion = 19
targetSdkVersion = 25
compileSdkVersion = 25
buildToolsVersion = "25"
supportLibraryVersion = "25.0.0"
```

And this is my `dependencies` in `project_name/build.gradle` file :

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

As Vishnu said, For me updating Android studio and Gradle didn't fix the problem.

I navigated to Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager and selected BuildTools and checked for the updates related to platform tools. After updating and installing those, fixed my problem.

And for one my friends, the issue got resolved after following the above steps and then navigating to Help->Check for updates-> and installing all the available updates.

Attached Screenshot for the same.
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 10):

I am facing similar issue after upgrading Android Studio to 3.0. A very simple way to fix this is go to

> Tools -> Android ->SDK Manager -> SDK Tools

There look for Android SDK platform tools and update it. (Screenshot attached)[image: SDK tools window image]

Thats it, you don't have to change any other gradle setting.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my SDK Platform versions but didn't find where to update SDK Platform-Tools version. Rebuild the project the warning disappears.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open `AndroidMainfest.xml`
2. Click the red icon => Disable inspection => Error is gone

[image]

Comment: Simple is that `-_-` BTW How to `undo` this? I want **AS** to inform me in future.

Comment: Don't do this, fix the issue, not ignore it.

Answer (score 4):

I face same problem but when I swap

```
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
```

to first line then problem solved. Then the final app grade become:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    compileSdkVersion 25

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.***"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 0
        versionName "0.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Update your android sdk platform-tools to the revision from 24.0.4 to 25.x.x on sdk manager. Then android studio click File->Invalidate Caches/Restart...

The error must be gone now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update

- Android SDK Build-Tools
- Android SDK Platform tools
- Android SDK Tools
- Android Support Repository
- Google Play Services
- Google repository

  etc to the latest version. Error must be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Gradle(app) and replace

```
  buildToolsVersion "25"
```

to

```
  buildToolsVersion "24.0.4" // Or Latest installed gradle version
```

also if `targetSdkVersion` is 25 then  make this 24

Comment: Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.4..? if i add this line in BuildToolsVersion ....?

Comment: create new project blank project and copy this gradle lines

Comment: but 24.0.4 is not availble in SDK "Manager"

Comment: create new project blank project and copy this gradle lines :)

Comment: No Its Not Working

Comment: this does not provide an answer to the question, you can't force OP to downgrade the target sdk and buildtools

Answer (score 0):

On command line

```
./sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-26"
./sdkmanager --list
```

Check if you have update to latest release